# Update from Mac OS X 10.6.8 to the newest version

Tags: macos, upgrade, software-update

I want to update from Mac OS X 10.6.8 to the newest version which is macOS Sierra. My Mac should be able to run this version of macOS. If I try to download the update on the App Store it fails because I need Mac OS X 10.7 at least.

What can I do to upgrade my Mac?

Comment: Install 10.7 first (duh?)

Comment: I'd think twice before upgrading, or buy more RAM before you do. How fast is your computer right now, how much RAM do you have, do you have an HDD or SSD? Sierra will probably run significantly slower than Snow Leopard and I'd recommend at least 4GB and an SSD or at least 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how Apple says you can upgrade via their [macOS upgrade page](http://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/).  You need to install an intermediate upgrade first.

### Upgrading from OS X Snow Leopard

If you’re running Snow Leopard (10.6.8) and your Mac supports macOS Sierra, you will need to upgrade to El Capitan [from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?mt=12) first. Then you can update to Sierra.

### Upgrading from OS X Leopard

If you’re running Leopard and would like to upgrade to macOS Sierra, first you’ll need to upgrade to OS X Snow Leopard. You can purchase OS X Snow Leopard from the [Apple Online Store](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard). Then upgrade to El Capitan as above, and then to Sierra.

Comment: Try going to the Purchased tab of the App Store and see if you can download it from there.

Comment: Here is the Apple Support article for installing El Capitan: https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT206886