# Update Macbook 8.1 from Snow Leopard to High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, software-update, high-sierra

So I have established that I have a Macbook 8.1 that apparently can run High Sierra. Problem is I can't download from app store because it says it requires 10.8.0 to perform that task.

The Macbook will be used by wife for mainly browsing, iTunes, word processing and other stuff. I have a PC with Linux and Hackintosh for all my heavy dev stuff so not worried about High Sierra running possibly slow but if it is dreadful I'll just update the RAM and possibly upgrade to an SSD.

I have been told that it might be a good idea to create a bootable DVD and install from that instead. So was wondering where I can get an official .iso (or .dmg?) of High Sierra or would you guys recommend taking it to Apple to do this?

Comment: How did you get the macOS for your Hackintosh?  Can't you download it from the App store on that machine?

Comment: Well its an AMD so got it from http://amd-osx.com/ so not sure if its the same thing? Are these images all the same or do different sources change the image abit? Also the download is a .dmg file that I turned into a bootable usb with transmac so could just use that?

Comment: From what I read, they don't supply an installer.  You have to source it.  I don't use Hackintosh, but it would be worth a shot to download an installer (or at least attempt to do so.)

Comment: Looks like I need to upgrade to El Captain first. According to the apple site. https://www.apple.com/au/macos/how-to-upgrade/ so will give that a go tonight and then get back to this thread.

Comment: Ahhh kk I did not know macOS is free. I thought you paid for the OS like you would Windows. :)

Comment: Technically, it's provided at no charge for use on a Mac computer.

Comment: Be sure to self-answer this question if you solve it yourself.

Comment: I guess that your Mac is a old Mac as it's running SL. I will advise against installation of High Sierra on it. It will be terribly slow even if you put SSD and RAM as it runs slowly on a 2011 MacBook Pro i7.

Comment: @PratikaRana Having run High Sierra on a 5,1, the issue was really only that I was disk and memory bound (4GB.) With those fixed, it should be just fine for day-to-day tasks.

Comment: amd-osx is not an official source, and their installers may be modified as well. If the El Cap thing works for you, post that as an answer and you can mark it as solved as @Wildcard suggested

Comment: Will probably get back to this next week sometime, need to fix the track pad which stopped work. Might also get some new Ram in the meantime.

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253836/update-from-mac-os-x-10-6-8-to-the-newest-version